# How do you negate a rule in Rules 2?

Tags: rules

I'm working with a Drupal 6 tutorial (but building in Drupal 7) that uses the Rules module, and I notice that some of the rules the presenter is building rely upon negation (e.g. "if NOT blah-blah") Am I missing something, or is this possibility not available in the Drupal 7 version of the module?

Answer (score 4):

**Rule conditions** may be negated by checking the Negate checkbox ("If checked, the condition result is negated such that it returns TRUE if it evaluates to FALSE.") You can't negate a rule event or an action.